# python reshape with new size [matlab like]

Tags: python, matlab, reshape

I am working to translate matlab code to python code.

I want to implement reshape like matlab.

the matlab code is:

```
reshape(array,size1,[])
```

I want to reshape 2D shape with one input size. How can I implement it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Ali's answer, you can use -1 in place of any dimension to calculate it's size. For example:

```
array = np.random.randint(1,100,100)
array_reshaped = array.reshape(2, -1)
```

`array_reshaped` will be a 2 x 50 array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to do most of the array operations you can do with `matlab`

```
import numpy as np
# create a random 1D array of size 100
array = np.random.randint(1,100,100)
# reshape the array to a 2D form
array = np.reshape(array, (2,50))
# reshape the array back to the 1D form
array = np.reshape(array, (100,))
```

Comment: I want to reshape the array to the N(input) by M( auto calculation).
Your advise just for normal use of reshape in numpy.

Comment: So you need to edit you question add more details to explain what exactly you want.

Comment: I just want to find easy way to translate matlab code to python. I want to know if python have this method function.